# How to get content from JSON.parse(xhr.response)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, get, xmlhttprequest

I send a GET request to the client and objects in the body are returned to me. Now I need to work with one specific object, for example, display the name of the object under ID 3. How can I do this?

```js
const requestURL = '/coffee/all'

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', requestURL)

xhr.onload = () => {

    var datas = JSON.parse(xhr.response);

    console.log(datas)
}

xhr.send()
```

[image]

Comment: there is no object with ID 3 ... but if there were you'd find it by using `let object = datas.content.find(({id}) => id === 3)`

Comment: You probably meant index 3 not item 3? If so you can access it by just `datas.content[3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const requestURL = '/coffee/all'
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', requestURL)

xhr.onload = () => {

    var datas = JSON.parse(xhr.response);

    console.log(datas.find(item => item.id === 3).name)
}

xhr.send()
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Answers are easier to understand if you provide an explanation along with the code